# How to reference a class from another method in C#?

Tags: c#, class

I have a NetworkStream in another Method but how would I reference it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Adventurer3
{
    class Adv3API
    {
        public Adv3API()
        {

        }


        public void Connect(string Ip)
        {
            string server = Ip;
            Int32 port = 8899;
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        }


        public string SendGCode(string GCODE, string Ip)
        {
            string message = "~" + GCODE;
            Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            data = new Byte[256];
            String responseData = String.Empty;
            Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
            return responseData;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to use stream.Write but I cant because it is in another method.

How can I do this?

Comment: You could make the `Connect` method a function that returns a `NetworkStream`. Make sure that you call  [`.Dispose()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dispose?view=net-5.0) on the stream as soon as you've finished using it.

Comment: can you give an example because when I do that it creates a new client each time @AndrewMorton

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like there's enough code—such as where you are calling `Connect()`—in the question for me to be able to suggest what to add where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On connect store the stream in a member var, when you disconnect dispose of it? If it's a member variable you could access it from any method.